# Can I go out of the airport while a layover at Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, singapore

I am an Indian citizen and I have a flight to Japan with a 7 hour layover at Singapore. I only have a temporary visitor visa for Japan. I was wondering if I could go out of the airport and visit Singapore, and what additional procedures(if any) I might require for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=sg&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of India who can also
>   transit, for up to 96 hours without a visa under the Visa Free
>   Transit Facility (VFTF) on either the outbound or return leg
>   of the same journey (but not on both). **Leaving the transit
>   area is allowed.**
>
> **Warning**: Holders of a valid single entry visa (or
>      multiple entry visa valid for at least one month) issued by
>      Australia, Canada, Germany, **Japan**, New Zealand,
>      Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom to nationals of India
>      may use the VFTF mentioned above. After using a single
>      entry visa and the VFTF was not used on the outbound leg of
>      the journey, the VFTF can only be used on the return leg
>      with a direct transit through Singapore from the country
>      that issued the visa to the country of residence (e.g.,
>      SYD-SIN-PEK).

So yes, you **can** visit Singapore. Present your passport open at the page with the Japanese visa, and your connecting ticket.

Comment: 7 hours is actually plenty for Singapore, the airport even has free transit tours.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/new_delhi/visa_information/overview.html

```
Indian nationals who are in transit to or from any third country by air, may be eligible for the 96-hour VFTF for one transit in the itinerary (either forward or return leg, but not both) if they:

   i. have a valid onward air ticket departing within the next 96-hours; and

  ii. possess a valid visa/long-term pass (with a validity of at least 1 month from the date of entry into Singapore under the VFTF) issued by any of the following countries**:

          a. Australia
          b. Canada
          c. Japan
          d. New Zealand
          e. United Kingdom
          f. United States of America
          g. Germany
          h. Switzerland

** A visa is considered valid if it is not expired and is good for entry into the third country.
** The VFTF for Indian nationals is for air to air travel only, and is only valid for one transit in the itinerary (either forward or return leg, but not both).
```